# Create button in NGUI

Tags: unity, gui, ngui

I try to create a button with the help of the NGUI. Here are screenshots of me doing that:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

So the problem here is the next. When clicking play button in game mode I hope to get the following line in the console:

`play`.

But actually nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?